# Why did Apache IoTDB automatically switched the data type back to the previous setting?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now using Apache IoTDB Version 1.0. The data type written is reset to be INT type in the code (the previous type is in FLOAT), but when the data was written, the data type still becomes FLOAT. I want to know why the data type is automatically switched and how can I successfully set the data type to be INT type?

how to deal this question,someone help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write data in this time series using the Cli tool of Apache IoTDB before? You can check your data directory, and if so you can just delete the "float" type data and rewrite them.